# Quotient Group of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ proofs

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

> In each of the following $H$ is a subset of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$. I want to:
>
> a) Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$.
>
> b) In geometrical terms, describe he elements of the quotient group.
>
> c) Describe the operation of $G/H$.
>
> 1. $H=\{(x,0): x\in \mathbb R\}$
> 2. $H=\{(x,y): y=-x\}$
> 3. $H=\{(x,y): y=2x\}$

For 1.  I believe that $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ is abelian , thus making $H$ normal as long as it is a subgroup of $G$. So suppose some $x_1, x_2 \in H$, then $x_1+(x_2)=(x_1, 0)+(x_2,0)=(x_1+x_2, 0) \in H$. $H$ so its closed under addition. Now I need to prove negation.  Geometrically, $H$ is all the lines parallel to the horizontal line through the x-axis. I think the operation would be addition.

For 2. Similar to 1, showing $H$ is a subgroup. Let some $y_1, y_2 \in H$ then $y_1+y_2=(-x_1)+(-x_2)=-(x_1+x_2) \in H$. So H is closed. Now to prove negation, that is: $(-x,-y) \rightarrow -y=-(-x) \rightarrow -y=x$ which is the negation of $y=-x$. Geometrically, $H$ is all the lines parallel to the line through the origin with a negative slope. I believe the operation is addition.

For 3. Proving a subgroup: suppose some $y_1,y_2, x_1,x_2 \in H$ then $y_1+y_2=2x_1+(2x_2)=2(x_1+x_2) \in H$. For negation: Geometrically, $H$ is all the lines parallel to the line through the origin with slope 2. I believe the operation is addition.

I have edited to where I am currently at. I am working through negations.

Comment: What is the binary operation on $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$?

Comment: @Mathmo123  What *is* multiplication under $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ was that ever defined?

Comment: Okay, first of all is $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ even a group? It is, if you give in a binary operation that satisfies the group axioms.  So which binary operation are you using.  How do you define $(x,y)\circ(w,z)$.  If it is $(x,y)\circ(w,z)= (x+w, y+z)$ then it is a group (you can prove it). If $(xy)\circ(w,z) = xw + xa +yw + y+z$ that not only is NOT a group operation.  It's not even a binary operation as the result is NOT a member or $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.

Comment: @fleablood I have no binary operation. I just know that $H$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ x $\mathbb R$ so the elements in $H$ will be of the form $(x,y)$

Comment: If you do not have a binary operation you do not have a group.  And the question has no answer.  I assume you *do* have a group operation on $\mathbb R \times  \mathbb R$. Go back through your text and see.  I also suspect, (but don't know for sure) that is is addition as defined $(x,y) + (w,v) = (x+w, y+v)$.  If so then $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ *is* a group and  $(x,0) + (y, 0) = (x+y, 0)$

Comment: Forget $H$.  In $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ what is $(x,y)\cdot(w,v)$?

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts are, without the operation being specified, we must be considering $\mathbb{R}^2$ under addition. I don't think there are any other operations you could assume would be on $\mathbb{R}^2$, without it being explicitly provided. Unfortunately, this makes the question a little simple and repetitive, but I'll do part 2, and you can fill in the rest.

(a) First, note that $(0, 0)$, the group identity, is in $H$, as $0 = -0$.

Suppose $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) \in H$. Then $y_1 = -x_1$ and $y_2 = -x_2$, which implies
$$y_1 + y_2 = -(x_1 + x_2) \implies (x_1, y_1) + (x_2, y_2) = (x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2) \in H.$$
Thus $H$ is closed under the group operation. Note also that given $(x, y) \in H$, the inverse element $(-x, -y)$ satisfies $-y = -(-x)$, since $y = -x$, so $(-x, -y) \in H$. Therefore $H$ is a subgroup. (As you said, it's normal because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is abelian.)

(b) Two points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$ are in the same coset if and only if
$$(x_1, y_1) - (x_2, y_2) = (x_1 - x_2, y_1 - y_2) \in H.$$
Therefore, we have $y_1 - y_2 = -(x_1 - x_2)$, or equivalently, $x_1 + y_1 = x_2 + y_2$. So really, we just need to look at the sum of the coordinates to determine which coset we're in - when the sums are the same, the points are in the same coset, and when they're different, they're in different cosets. Our cosets will all be the solution sets of equations of the form $x + y = k$, for fixed $k$.

Geometrically, these equations describe all the parallel lines to $y = -x$. Note that, as cosets should, these partition the plane.

(c) Now that we have a parameter to describe which coset $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ belongs to (i.e. $x + y$), we can describe the operation on $G/H$. If we add cosets $(x_1, y_1) + H$ and $(x_2, y_2) + H$, then the resulting coset is $(x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2) + H$, which has the parameter $(x_1 + y_1) + (x_2 + y_2)$.

That is, the operation on $G/H$ takes the sets of all pairs whose coordinates sum to $k_1$ and $k_2$ respectively, and produces the set of pairs whose coordinates sum to $k_1 + k_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your example! Do you believe I should assume $\mathbb R^2$  is under addition for all three parts? I can see how this would make the problem easier.

Comment: Yeah, I think so. As I said, there's really no other operation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that can be be attached without explicitly defining it. Unless you've literally only copied half the question, it is going to be $+$, for all parts.